# C++ class constructor clears map

Tags: c++, constructor, stdmap

My first constructor edits a member `std::map` and then calls another constructor. At the end of the first constructor the size of the map is 2, and at the start of the second constructor it's 0. What is causing this?

Here is my header file:

```
// Test.h
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(std::string name, int age);
private:
    Test();

    std::map<std::string, int> myMap_;
}
```

And here is my code:

```
// Test.cpp
#include "test.h"

Test::Test()
{
    std::cout << myMap_.size() << std::endl; // Outputs 0
}

Test::Test(std::string name, int age)
{
    myMap_.insert(name, age);
    myMap_.insert("test", 6);

    std::cout << myMap_.size() << std::endl; // Outputs 2
    Test();
}
```

EDIT:
And here is my main function:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    Test t("yo", 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a constructor of another object... You want to construct the same thing twice? You can't. There are delegating constructors, but this is not how you do it.

Comment: @LogicStuff I don't want to construct the thing twice, i have 3 constructors: Test1, Test2 and Test3. Test1 and Test2 operate on the map and then ask Test3 to finish it off since they both have to run the same code then. I could use another method like init() to do this for me, but it's still part of the construction so i thought it would be a better idea if a constructor did it.

Comment: @Resantic even better would be to use the ctor-initializer feature to initialize class members. If you post some real code then someone will be able to suggest a good way to organize it.

Comment: @M.M That wouldn't be possible because the constructors do not only intialize class members.

Comment: @Resantic To be honest if you want to operate on the map you should provide the corresponding elements that would perform those operations.A constructor is meant for initialization, if you want to populate the map with some default values during the object's initialization process then you should declare a new member function that would perform this initialization.

Comment: @Resantic Tricks there are, young jedi

Comment: @Resantic when you have c++11 available there are ways to do this (e.g. initializer lists)

Comment: @StamatisLiatsos Well the class actually creates a texture atlas/spritesheet, and the map contains the images in the spritesheet, so it it part of the construction, atleast in my opinion.

Comment: @Resantic Ok then, but the construction should happen inside the current constructor context. Call a separate function-member of the class that will populate the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second constructor inserts 2 elements. So the size is 2.

The first constructor inserts no elements. So the size is 0.

---

I guess maybe you expect `Test();` inside the second constructor to "call the other constructor" for the same object.  However this does not happen. Constructors are different to regular functions.

The code `Test();` actually means to create a temporary object of type `Test`, which is initialized by calling the default constructor. Then that object is destroyed immediately, since it was temporary.

Constructors have no name, as far as *name lookup* is concerned, it's not possible to call them like regular functions.  Instead they are invoked when you give the syntax to create an object.

If you want to have some common code that is shared by multiple constructors; you could either put that code in a function that is called by the multiple constructors, or use the [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) feature. In the latter case, the delegation must happen before any statements inside the constructor body are executed.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually calling the constructor on the same object but create a temporary new one, which then has no name. See it as the same as this:

```
Test::Test(std::string name, int age)
{
    myMap_.insert(name, age);
    myMap_.insert("test", 6);

    std::cout << myMap_.size() << std::endl; // Outputs 2
    Test other = Test(); //you create a new object here
}
```

In C++11 you can do something like you want to do with this (this is called constructor delegation):

```
Test::Test(std::string name, int age)
:Test()
{
    myMap_.insert(name, age);
    myMap_.insert("test", 6);

    std::cout << myMap_.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The difference here though is the `Test()` constructor will be called before the insert operations on the map.

Comment: Yeah thats why "something like" and not exactly. I will add it to the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two instances of a Test.

The first instance of a `Test`, which is constructed with the name and age, inserts elements into its `myMap_` but the second instance does not.

When you call `Test()` in the `Test(name, age)` constructor **it is creating a second instance of Test locally** using the `Test()` constructor which does not insert into the map. This second instance would then be almost immediately destroyed (as it is not assigned to anything).

I think you are attempting to use two constructors on the same object, but that is only done for *inheriting* objects, where each derivation needs to call its own constructor and call its base.

You could create a function and call that instead:

```
// Test.h
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(std::string name, int age);
    void OutputSize();

private:
    Test();

    std::map<std::string, int> myMap_;
}

Test::Test(std::string name, int age)
{
    myMap_.insert(name, age);
    myMap_.insert("test", 6);

    OutputSize();
}

void Test::OutputName()
{
   std::cout << myMap_.size() << std::endl; // Outputs 2
}
```

Comment: There is no difference in construction between polymorphic objects and non-polymorphic ones. If a class has a base class (polymorphic or not) then the base class constructor is called before initializing members of the derived class. (initializing a base is the same operation as initializing a member, really)

Comment: Quite right, I meant inheriting over polymorphism.
What I was trying to highlight is that is the only time I can think of where you are calling multiple constructors on the same object, as you call the derived class's constructor and the base's as well.